# Google Places API gives one result for correct spelling and all results for incorrect spelling

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

We use google places API to pull local data.

For a particular query - `Saint Louis Renters Insurance` we get only one result as shown in the image below :

[image: One result for 'Saint Louis Renters Insurance' query]

But when the same query is spelled incorrectly `Siant Louis Renters Insurance` [spelling mistake in the word 'Saint'] , we get all the results as shown in the image below :

[image: Many results for 'Siant Louis Renters Insurance' query]

Could anyone tell me whats happening here? I posted this question in the Google Places API group but some how my post got deleted, as you can see in the below image, which is pretty annoying :

[image]

It would be real bad if google places api starts giving less results for correct querys.

Answer (score 2):

The Places API always returns the best results it can, so if you're filtering by text or exact keywords and there's a good string match, it will return only that.  Multiple results are only returned if it's not confident enough about correctness.

If you simply want to return a list of all possible insurance agencies in St Louis, try a Nearby Search with a latlng in St Louis, a suitable radius (10 km below) and a `types=insurance_agency` filter:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=insurance_agency&sensor=false&location=38.597051,-90.217889&radius=10000&skip_auth

Comment: Yeah! But both "Saint Louis Renters Insurance" and "Siant Louis Renters Insurance" returns the same set of local result when queried in browser, so which means Google doesn't show up local businesses using the Places API data. Am i correct?

Comment: Hmm?  The Places API is completely different from Google web search!

Comment: Yes it is! Also in that it won't return **all** possible insurance agencies in St Louis, just the *most relevant* ones for your request.